# Bash update issue

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting

I have Ubuntu 12.04 with 3.2.0-49-generic kernel.

Up to 3 days ago, I was working fine with Bash Scripting. Yesterday I did an `apt-get` update and upgrade and since then I have been having problems with bash scripting. Does anybody know whether a new bug was introduced? Or if there was any changes to the commands I try to call?

```
for line in `cat file.txt`;do echo " $line,";done
```

The comma appears at the beginning end not at end as I expect. I don’t know if something is wrong with new bash version, but I guess yes.

If I do not place a space before `$line`, bash deletes the first character of the line.

As I said, all of this was working 3 days ago.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `file.txt` contains DOS line endings, which cause the cursor to move to the beginning of the line after print the value of `$line` but before printing the comma. Remove them using `dos2unix`. Also, you should iterate over a file using the `read` command and a `while` loop, since your current method will fail for lines containing whitespace:

```
while read -r line; do
    echo " $line,"
done < file.txt
```

Note that none of this has anything to do with the version of `bash` you are using.

Comment: Thanks a lot, im begginner on this, and i dont know about formats, i ready learned about dos2unix and its works, Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

The chances are high that your file, `file.txt`, has CRLF (DOS) line endings.  Maybe you copied the file from a Windows machine.  Fix with `dos2unix`, `tr`, `vim` or sundry other methods.